# nginx-digest always return 401

Tags: docker, nginx, nginx-config, digest-authentication

This is my configuration in nginx.conf, and my nginx image is supported nginx-digest already, but I don't know my web page after I fill in my username and password, the nginx log shows 401 to me.

[image]

[image]